# How can I compile multiple less files in their own less folder with a single command?

Tags: compilation, less

I had tried to compile all the files at once by installing `lessc-each` with the help of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lessc-each) doc with the following project structure:

```
-project
    --less-files
```

I was compiling multiple less files using `lessc-each <source-dir> <destination-dir>`. And it was working fine.

Now, for a complex project structure like

```
-project
    --Component1
        --css
            --less-files
    --Component2
        --css
            --less-files
    --Component3
        --css
            --less-files
```

I want that when I compile less files, the auto-created css files reside in the same folder.

Means, I want this structure after compilation:

```
-project
    --Component1
        --css
            --less-files
            --after-compilation-css-files
    --Component2
        --css
            --less-files
            --after-compilation-css-files
    --Component3
        --css
            --less-files
            --after-compilation-css-files
```

How can I achieve it using single command?